# jQuery Validate does not work on custom radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I use jQuery Validate plugin for a form. By now I have not succeeded in validating my custom radio buttons. I have read many posts on how to solve this problem, for example using `ignore`, but this has not helped.

Here comes my little code:

**HTML**

```
<form id="my-form" name="my-form" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="myText">

    <p></p>

    <input type="radio" id="my-radio-1" name="myRadio">
    <label for="my-radio-1">selection #1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="my-radio-2" name="myRadio">
    <label for="my-radio-2">selection #2</label>

    <p></p>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" id="my-submit">
    </p>

</form>
```

**JS**

```
$('#my-form').validate({
    rules: {
        myText: {
            required: true
        },
        myRadio: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    errorClass: 'error_validate',
    errorPlacement: function (label, element) {
        label.insertAfter(element);
    }
});
```

**JSFIDDLE with CSS:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/d0nf4pqf/

Anybody knows how to enable validation for the radio buttons?

Comment: @charlietfl I don't know what you mean. could you please make this modification in my jsfiddle, save a new version and post the link? thanks

Comment: All you have to do is to add `ignore` option, because your native radios are in fact hidden. Hidden elements are NOT validated by default, unless they're removed from *validate's* `ignore` array : https://jsfiddle.net/bywnwL77/

Answer (score 10):

The problem is intersting. You are using custom styles for radio buttons, and how it works, is that CSS rules hide native `input` and display styled CSS radio instead. As the result, radio inputs are *hidden*, but jQuery validation plugin ignores hidden form elements by default.

To fix it you need to instruct plugin that you want hidden fields to be validated too. Use `ignore` option for this:

```
$('#my-form').validate({
    // specify rules
    ignore: [],
    rules: {
        myText: {
            required: true
        },
        myRadio: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    // change name of error class that is assigned to input fields
    errorClass: 'error_validate',
    errorPlacement: function (label, element) {
        // default
        if (element.is(':radio')) {
            label.insertAfter(element.next('label'));       
        }
        else {
            label.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

Also note, that you need to fix `errorPlacement` function in this case too. You can't append error element immediately after input, because (once again due to custom radio styles) then radio check/uncheck won't work (it uses adjacent sibling selector `+`).

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/d0nf4pqf/1/

Comment: You're a Genius !